# two way binding doesn't seem to work. List is not automatically updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having troubles updating a list. At first I fill my list by fetching information from a $http.get request. Later I enter something in a text box and I try to update the list with the response of the $http.post request.

I do get a response and I have the data. When I overwrite the variable that is in $scope the list doesn't update.

My code looks like this:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.friends', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/friends', {
            templateUrl: 'friends/friends.html',
            controller: 'FriendsCtrl'
        });
    }])

    .controller('FriendsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, UserService) {
        $scope.items = [];

        $scope.formSearchData = {};

        UserService.getAll().then(function(data) {
            var remoteItems = data;

            for (var i = 0; i < remoteItems.length; i++) {
                var object = {};
                object.name = remoteItems[i].name;
                object.id = remoteItems[i]._id;
                $scope.items.push(object);
            }
        });

        $scope.itemClick = function(value) {
            console.dir(value);
        };

        $scope.submitForm = function() {
            //debugger;
            $scope.items[0].name = "John D";
            UserService.getSearchResult($scope.formSearchData).then(function(data) {
                getSearchResult(data);
            });
        };

        function getSearchResult(data) {
            var remoteItems = data.records;
            $scope.items = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < remoteItems.length; i++) {
                var object = {};
                object.name = remoteItems[i].name;
                object.id = remoteItems[i].id;
                $scope.items.push(object);
            }
        }
    })

    .controller('navigationcontroller', function ($scope, $location) {
        $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
            return viewLocation = $location.path();
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-title">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="friend-search" ng-controller="FriendsCtrl">
            <form ng-submit="submitForm()">
                <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Zoek vrienden" class="form-control" ng-model="formSearchData.search">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-title">
    <div class="panel-default">
        <div class="scrollable-content" ui-scroll-bottom='bottomReached()' ng-controller="FriendsCtrl">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="items" class="list-group-item" ng-click="itemClick(item)">
                    {{ item.name }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The UserService is a factory that has the two functions, one for the GET request and one for the POST request. It looks like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp').factory('UserService', function($http) {
    return {
        getAll: function() {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:3030/user/all').then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        },

        getSearchResult: function(query) {
            return $http.post('http://localhost:3030/user/search', query, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I read something about $scope being out of scope and try to solve it by using $scope.apply() or $scope.$digest but I get errors when I try that. Also I tried adding tracking in the html but that also doesn't seem to work.

As you can see I also tried to hardcode update the list, that also doesn't seem to work.

I'm very new to Angular and this is keeping me busy for days now. I hope someone can help me. Any suggestions to my code are welcome as well ;) . Thanks!

Comment: your snippets don't work cause angular is not defined, please fix

Comment: multiple controllers don't share scope, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunker of your code working with just one controller. I modified it a little since I don't have your API endpoints, but the returned object is a promise and hence data gets displayed correctly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/iEWBm6QE2pmFqbsU6EiB?p=preview

The reason your code doesn't work as you intend is because you have declared the controller twice in the HTML.

**From the angular docs:**

"When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be created and made available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor function as $scope."

**Meaning:**

When you declare another ng-controller, it has its own child scope, it does not share scope with any other controller. And your items are declared on only one scope.

Relevant code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope, UserService){

  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.formSearchData = {};

  UserService.getAll().then(function(data) {
      $scope.saved = data;

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.saved.length; i++) {
          var object = {};
          object.name = $scope.saved[i].name;
          object.id = $scope.saved[i]._id;
          $scope.items.push(object);
      }
  });

  $scope.itemClick = function(value) {
      console.dir(value);
  };

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
      UserService.getSearchResult($scope.formSearchData).then(function(data) {
          console.log( data );
          if( data ){
            $scope.items = data;
          } else {
            $scope.data = $scope.saved;
          }

      });
  };



}]); 

app.factory('UserService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getAll: function() {
          return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve(
              [{
                name: 'test'
              }, {
                name: 'test2'
              }]
            );
          });
            /*return $http.get('http://localhost:3030/user/all').then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });*/
        },

        getSearchResult: function(query) {
          return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve( [{
              name: 'test'
            }]);
          });
          /*  return $http.post('http://localhost:3030/user/search', query, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });*/
        } 
    }; 
});
```

Comment: You are right! I've changed my HTML so that both the text and list are in the same div and added the controller on that. Than it immediately works.